# SolrCloud connection timeout pool

Tags: solrj, solrcloud, apache-zookeeper

I have solr cloud cluster and it is throwing the following exception, it is happening when solr does something with the replicas

null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://10.14.0.72:8080/solr/IE_big_index_shard1_0_replica2
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:407)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:155)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2033)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:652)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:460)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:229)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://10.14.0.72:8080/solr/IE_big_index_shard1_0_replica2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:591)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:230)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:482)
    ... 12 more

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using? And try to investigate further what happens when "Solr does something with the replicas".

Comment: solr 6.0.0. I was playing with zookeeper timeouts increasint them until 60 s but the exception is happening.